# accessing images in laravel 8 after hosting are not working

Tags: php, laravel

I developed a project in laravel8 and hosted it in the shared server after hosting it I did not know whether a symbolic link was destroyed or disabled by the server. Images are stored in the storage folder but not automatically copied in the public folder and now I can't access image in views pages

Comment: use the command php artisan storage:link. supporting document - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: images are not displayed in view pages

Comment: Please add all clarification to your questin by editing it, along with the code that is needed to reproduce the problem and your attempts to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `php artisan storage:link` command.

If you don't access to ssh, you can do like this:

```
Route::get('generate', function (){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('storage:link');
    echo 'ok';
});
```

Comment: command is executed successfully but does not effect any thing

Comment: @WarisAkbari check your path of your image

Comment: sir path is correct the problem is here that laravel 8 after hosting does not copy image to public folder as it does in in development environment

Answer (score 0):

To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

**FMI**: Visit the below link => https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem